# VMR9 Allocator and SwapEffect.Discard

Tags: directx, directshow.net

I'm developing an application using a VMR9 Allocator.

The allocator allow me to draw the directshow filter graph output to a texture. 
I noticed that if I don't use the *SwapEffect.Copy* in exclusive mode my video rate is bellow 25 (the nominal rate).

I need to use *SwapEffect.Discard* in order to activate multisampling.

Is there any workaround to use vmr9 allocator with *SwapEffect.Discard*?

Comment: Do you have a small sample code? That would come in quite handy.

Comment: The code is pretty huge because allocator needs a big amount of code. Anyway I was able to perform this by modifying the vmr9allocator sample in Microsoft SDKs\Windows\V7. Now I have to check against my code to see what is wrong.